# How to install dependent role on specific host with ansible

Tags: ansible

I have the following `role/meta/main.yml` script:

```
---
dependencies:
  - role: common
  - role: nginx
  - role: postgres
  - role: my_db
```

And I need to install the `my_db` role on a specific host, lets say `1.2.3.4`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to install one roll, you should create a playbook which only applies that role to the host.

```
- hosts:
    - 1.2.3.4
  roles:
    - my_db
```

Comment: Hello, @udondan , could you please be more specific? Since i am trying to install all 4 roles as stated in my question.

    dependencies:
         - role: common
         - role: nginx
         - role: postgres
         - role: my_db

Comment: Then I don't understand the question. You wrote you only want to install the role my_db on the host.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was:

```
---
dependencies:
-hosts: 4.3.2.1
  roles:common nginx postgres

-hosts: 1.2.3.4
  roles:my_db
```

And it installs `my_db` role on my `1.2.3.4` host specifically.